# Ethereum Wallet stuck pending transaction

Tags: transactions

NOOB here trying to get a handle on things.

I've been using the Ethereum Wallet from Ethereum.org for about a year.  I'm on ver 0.10.0.  Around December 2017 - January 2018 I started to have very strange issues.  I could receive Eth but I could not always send Eth.  It would take 2 or 3 attempts.  By that I mean I would configure to send some Eth and I could see the transaction in my wallet.  I could go out to Etherscan and see it "pending".  then it would disappear from my wallet with no record of the transaction and same with Etherscan.  I would recreate the send action and sometimes the second or third attempt would finally go.  I would see the transaction in my wallet and on Etherscan.

Then sometime February-March the same issue was happening but I would no longer see the completed transaction in my wallet.  Etherscan showed the transaction.  My wallet was debited the correct amount but no local transaction record.  More and more I would have try sending Ether multiple times for it to go through.

In April, no send transactions were recorded in my wallet.  Etherscan recorded them properly.  To get the send to go through I would have to recreate the transaction 4-5-6 times.

Now in May no send transactions work.  The last two sends to shapeshift seem to be stuck.  Nothing shows in my wallet, my balance hasn't changed.  Etherscan shows 1 sometimes 2 transactions that are "pending".  Other times, they are not there.  My balance still seems correct in both my wallet and Etherscan.

I have tried geth --removedb
I've tried geth --syncmode=fast --  cache=4096
I've removedb and let Ethereum Wallet sync
I've completely uninstalled Ethereum Wallet and reinstalled.

My Ethereum Wallet balance seems correct but still I have a pending transaction on Etherscan that seems to be blocking me from sending anything else.

I'm looking for ideas on how to clear this and be able to send again.

Comment: Looking in the log this is the last entries....

Comment: [2018-05-16T12:32:26.885] [INFO] (ui: browser) - Node started syncing, stopping app operation
[2018-05-16T12:32:26.961] [INFO] EthereumNode - INFO [05-16|12:32:26] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=5.027ms   number=5624485 hash=5f59f6…5c4738 ignored=0

[2018-05-16T12:32:27.387] [INFO] (ui: browser) - Restart app operation again
[2018-05-16T12:32:27.387] [INFO] (ui: browser) - Connect to node...

Comment: [2018-05-16T12:32:27.395] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed { code: -32000, message: 'no suitable peers available' }
[2018-05-16T12:32:27.395] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed { code: -32000, message: 'no suitable peers available' }
[2018-05-16T12:32:27.397] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed { code: -32000, message: 'no suitable peers available' }

Comment: [2018-05-16T12:32:27.397] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed { code: -32000, message: 'no suitable peers available' }
[2018-05-16T12:32:27.399] [INFO] (ui: browser) - Couldn't check Token code of  { address: '0x89205a3a3b2a69de6dbf7f01ed13b2108b2c43e7',
  name: 'Unicorns',
  symbol: '',
  balances: {},
  decimals: 0,
  disabled: true,
  _id: 'token_89205a3a3b' } {}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you can sometimes cancel/replace your transaction by  following  the steps listed in this guide https://kb.myetherwallet.com/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html

It is not guaranteed to work, and if it doesn't you will be forced to wait until your transaction has been replaced. Best of luck!